# data being hidden by &nbsp; and class regenerated when scraping web page using Beautiful Soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hidden-field

I am trying to pull pricing data from a website, but each time the page is loaded, thet class is regenerated to a different sequence of letters, and the price is showing `&nbsp;` instead of a number. Is there a technique that I can use to bypass this in any way? Thanks! Here is the line of html as how it appears when I inspect the element:

```
<div class="zlgJQq">$</div>
    <div class="qFwqmC hkVukg2 njGalW">&nbsp;</div>
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As mhawke said, share the URL. Can't help without it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps that website is actively discouraging you from scraping their data. That would explain the apparently random class names. You might want to read their terms of use to be sure that it's OK to scrape their site.

However, if the raw HTML does not contain the price data but it is visible when the page is rendered, then it's likely that Javascript is being used to insert the prices after the page has loaded. You could try enabling the developer tools in your browser and monitoring the network activity while the page is loading. That might reveal that the site is using dynamic [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) queries to populate the price data, and you could then write code to interact with the Ajax resource directly.

It's also possible that the price data is embedded somewhere in the HTML, possibly obfuscated, and then loaded dynamically by javascript.

That's just a couple of suggestions. You will need to analyse the site to see whether automated scraping is feasible. If you can let us know what website you're dealing with then someone might be able to suggest something more specific.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to add link here, but I am also facing the same problem. You can go to `tradingview` website and see the live price of gold. scraping that price give empty string.